# How to specifically scale model using pinch gesture in either lengthwise of bredthwise?

Tags: arcore, sceneform

i have a model. i want to just scale in up or down lengthwise rather than in every axes.
How can i tweak into
scaleController and pinch gesture to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make use of the - **public class TransformableNode**
Node that can be selected, translated, rotated, and scaled using gestures from TransformationSystem.
Pl. refer to the google developer link which explains how to use these API's
https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/sceneform/reference/com/google/ar/sceneform/ux/TransformableNode